# React native elevation not looking good in tablet view but looking good in mobile view

Tags: react-native, offset, shadow, android-elevation

React native elevation not looking good in tablet view but looking good in mobile view. I have given elevation as 5 for both mobile and tablet view for android. both the design shadow doesn't match. Is there a way i can achieve "shadowOffset" for android. I know that the shadowOffset is supported for only iOS. but i need similar kind of property in android. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us the code or the view.....

Answer (score 0):

try using [react-native-shadow-generator](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/) to help you with this.

Comment: I need shadowOffset property for android its supporting only ios. i need something like i need to show the shadows all around the edges equally